# Looking to enable/disable two networking adapters with Powerscript

Tags: windows, powershell, networking

I'm looking to make a basic Powerscript to enable wifi and disable ethernet if the ethernet adapter is up and vice versa. Was thinking something like

```
If (Get-NetAdapter ethernet == Status Up)
Enable-NetAdapter wi-fi
Disable-NetAdapter ethernet
Else
Enable-NetAdapter ethernet
Disable-NetAdapter wi-fi
```

but I am having issues with writing the if statement to actually get the status of the network adapter. How do I properly write the If statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a lot of about topics that come with powershell.

for the IF statement you can check :

```
Get-Help about_if
```

for what you are trying to do:

```
if( (Get-NetAdapter -Name ethernet).Status -eq 'UP')
{
   #some code
}
else
{
   #some code
}
```

Comment: Thank you, after adding some code to elevate powerscript this works perfectly!